# PipeGame -Why are the game objects not moving?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, timer, foreach

I'm wondering why my game objects are not showing. I am able to draw to the JPanel if I use `g.drawRect` outside of the for-each loop, but calling `PipeObject` inside of the loop doesn't seem to work for me. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for any help or solutions.

This is an updated version of my old question, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653372/pipe-game-pipeobject-in-class-pipeobject-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types).

**UPDATE** - The pipes are drawing correctly, but not moving to the left by calling `pipe.move()`.

Game

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
//import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
                final JPanel gui = new JPanel(cl);
                // remove if no border is needed
                //gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

                JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JButton playGame = new JButton("Play!");

                ActionListener playGameListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cl.show(gui, "game");
                    }
                };
                playGame.addActionListener(playGameListener);
                Insets margin = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
                playGame.setMargin(margin);
                menu.add(playGame);
                gui.add(menu);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(menu, "menu");

                final JPanel pipes = new Pipes();
                gui.add(pipes);
                cl.addLayoutComponent(pipes, "game");

                JFrame f = new JFrame("PipeGame");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Pipes

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Pipes extends JPanel {
    boolean gameNotOver = true;
    int x1 = 754;
    int y1 = setHeightVal();
    int y2 = setHeightVal();
    int y3 = setHeightVal();

    List<PipeObject> pipes = new ArrayList<PipeObject>();

    public Pipes() {
        pipes.add(new PipeObject(x1, y1));
        pipes.add(new PipeObject(x1 + 300, y2));
        pipes.add(new PipeObject(x1 + 600, y3));
    }

    public void drawEndlessPipes() {
        if (gameNotOver) {
            Timer pipeSpeed = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (PipeObject pipe : pipes) {
                        pipe.move();
                    }
                }
            });
            pipeSpeed.start();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (PipeObject pipe : pipes) {
            pipe.drawPipe(g);
        }
    }

    public int setHeightVal() {     //Get a random number and select a preset height
        int num = (int)(9*Math.random() + 1);
        int val = 0;
        if (num == 9)
        {
            val = 295;
        }
        else if (num == 8)
        {
            val = 246;
        }
        else if (num == 7)
        {
            val = 216;
        }
        else if (num == 6)
        {
            val = 185;
        }
        else if (num == 5)
        {
            val = 156;
        }
        else if (num == 4)
        {
            val = 125;
        }
        else if (num == 3)
        {
            val = 96;
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            val = 66;
        }
        else
        {
            val = 25;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(751,501);
    }
}
```

PipeObject

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class PipeObject {
    //Declare and initialiaze variables
    int x1;
    int x2 = 75;                //pipe width, total is 83
    int y1 = -1;                // Y should be -1
    int y2;
    int gap = 130;              //gap height

    public PipeObject(int x, int y) {
        this.x1 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
    }

    public void drawPipe(Graphics g/*, int x1, int y2*/) {
        g.drawRect(x1,y1,x2,y2);                        //Draw part 1
        g.drawRect(x1-3,y2-1,x2+6,25);                  //Draw part 2
        g.drawRect(x1-3,y2+25+gap,x2+6,25);             //Draw part 3
        g.drawRect(x1,y2+25+gap+25,x2,500-y2-49-gap);   //Draw part 4
    }

    public void move() {
        x1--;
    }

    public int getMyX() {   //To determine where the pipe is horizontally
        return x1-3;
    }

    public int getMyY() {   //To determine where the pipe is vertically
        return y2+25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you're still having problems? Without going through all your code, the answers below looked pretty valid. If it's still not working, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are painting the pipes beyond the visual bounds of the panel. The dimension of `Pipes` panel is `751x501`, but the pipes begin at `x1 = 754`. Try changing `x1` to `1` in `Pipes` and you should see the three pipes. Or, you can maximize the frame, and you should see the missing pipes far on the right side.

Comment: Did you see the timer though?

Comment: In theory, the pipes should move toward the left.

Comment: I will try that though

Comment: So, those pipes are drawing, but not moving

Comment: @CyberStorm as far as I can see the timer is never started. `drawEndlessPipes` is never called.

Comment: @CyberStorm Also, don't forget to call `repaint()` at the end of a `for` loop in the timer routine to repaint all the pipes at the new location.

Comment: @CyberStorm I got the pipes moving by adding a call to `drawEndlessPipes();` in `Pipes` constructor and adding `repaint();` after the `for` loop in timer's `actionPerformed()` method. Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you want to be of some more help. you could point me towards how to color those jpanels and loop the pipes endlessly. i know about setBackgroundColor, but im not exactly sure on how to use it in this case, since i have multiple panels in a card layout.

Comment: @CyberStorm to change color you set the color on the `Graphics`, ie `g.setColor(Color.RED);` You can introduce a member variable in `PipeObject` that indicates its color and then use it in `drawPipe()` method. See [Getting Started with Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/index.html) for some examples.

Comment: @CyberStorm as for cycling the pipes, you'd have to restore the original point of a pipe once it goes out of visual bounds. For example, inside `PipeObject.move()` check if `x1` became negative and reset it to the original value, ie, `754`. Of course, you'd have to make the logic a bit smarter to consider panel size, pipe size, avoid hard coded numbers, let the pipe disappear properly, support multiple pipes properly, etc.

Comment: sounds like a good plan to me, ill work on it when i get the chance

Answer (score 1):

As CyberStorm said, you never called drawEndlessPipes() to start the swing timer at all.
Also I don't see a repaint() call to Pipes panel inside your timer, just changing the x value won't magically move anything, you need to call repaint() in Pipes.java to make it repaint the screen and show animation.

So here it goes:

Modified **Runnable** in Game.java

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
            final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
            final JPanel gui = new JPanel(cl);
            // remove if no border is needed
            //gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

            JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton playGame = new JButton("Play!");

            ActionListener playGameListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cl.show(gui, "game");
                }
            };
            playGame.addActionListener(playGameListener);
            Insets margin = new Insets(20, 50, 20, 50);
            playGame.setMargin(margin);
            menu.add(playGame);
            gui.add(menu);
            cl.addLayoutComponent(menu, "menu");

            final JPanel pipes = new Pipes();
            gui.add(pipes);
            cl.addLayoutComponent(pipes, "game");

            JFrame f = new JFrame("PipeGame");
            f.add(gui);
            // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
            // all non-daemon threads are finished
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
            // in order display the components within it
            f.pack();
            // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
            // resizing artifacts.
            f.setVisible(true);

            ((Pipes) pipes).drawEndlessPipes();
        }
    };
```

Modified **drawEndlessPipes()** in Pipes.java

```
public void drawEndlessPipes() {
    if (gameNotOver) {
        Timer pipeSpeed = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (PipeObject pipe : pipes) {
                    pipe.move();
                    Pipes.this.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        pipeSpeed.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still only drawing a single pipe, and I need it to draw all three and I also need to make random pipes keep being scrolled endlessly